# MySql connection timeout with the database server machine using ODBC

Tags: mysql

In my application, I am reading data from a MySQL database using an ODBC connection string.

The connection string is like:

```
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;PORT=3306;Database=mysqltestdb;User=root;Password=1234;"
```

In the situation where the database server machine is switched off, I need to timeout immediately within a few seconds, say 5 seconds - it has to be a low timeout value.

How can I specify the timeout in the ODBC connection string, in case unable to establish connection with the database server machine? My application has a limitation that it can use only ODBC.

I have tried readtimeout=5;Connection Timeout=5;default command timeout=5;
but none of them is working.

EDIT 1:
If I deliberatly give a wrong IP address, then the timeout of 5 seconds seems to be working, but if I give correct IP address, but wrong port, then the timeout mentioned in the connection string does not work; it times out only after around 20 seconds. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "readtimeout" parameter in ODBC connection string. That parameter depends on your MySQl Server versión.

Check this out -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html